# Juno (Jupyter for iOS) specify directory to load dataset

Tags: ios, jupyter

I am trying to load a dataset into a notebook with. The dataset file file is in the same directory as the Juno notebook. The file name is correct.

I have tried removing the trailing ./ but it didn’t help.

df = pd.read_csv('./datatest.csv')

The error is that it can’t find the file. How can I specify the default directory or get the absolute path of a directory on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that both the notebook and the dataset was in a Dropbox folder. I'm not sure why it was the problem as all those files were downloaded locally on the phone and the option 'Make available offline' was set.

When I created a notebook in a local folder on the phone and the dataset was there, the error disappeared.